# How to restore a postgres database created via an older version of postgres?

Tags: postgresql, pg-restore

I have a file `db.backup`, that I would like to restore to PostgreSQL version 11.

When I tried to install via Azure Data Studio I got an error:

> Restore: pg_restore: [archiver] unsupported version (1.13) in file header

Then I found that running `pg_restore` I can actually read the file:

```
pg_restore /..db.backup -U postgres > db-restore.sql
```

And I can see that the file is human-readable. However I would much rather just restore the database from the backup.

How can I do this? I tried installing an older version of PostgreSQL server, but I don't know how to install an older version of PSQL (yet). Would this help?

Is there some flag I can add to the restore command so that the restore works?

-- EDIT

The output of `pg_restore --version`, i.e. the version of `pg_restore` that gave me the error message mentioned above:

> pg_restore (PostgreSQL) 11.4 (Ubuntu 11.4-1.pgdg18.04+1)

Comment: You should create the backup using `pg_dump` from your Postgres 11 installation.

Comment: I was provided the backup from a 3rd party - so I can't do that

Comment: _However I would much rather just restore the database from the backup._: that's just what your pg_restore command did. You can either play that SQL file with psql or add flags to pg_restore to do it into a database instead of into a SQL file, but the result is the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When I tried to install via Azure Data Studio I got an error:
>
> ```
> Restore: pg_restore: [archiver] unsupported version (1.13) in file header
> ```

Version 1.13 of the pg_dump archive format was introduced in February 2018 as part of the changes for [CVE-2018-1058](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/A_Guide_to_CVE-2018-1058:_Protect_Your_Search_Path). The version bump was mentioned in the [commit message](https://git.postgresql.org/gitweb/?p=postgresql.git;a=commit;h=3d2aed664ee8271fd6c721ed0aa10168cda112ea) with a specific warning about the problem:

> Since this change requires a change in the behavior of pg_restore when
>   processing an archive file made according to this new convention, bump
>   the archive file version number; **old versions of pg_restore will
>   therefore refuse to process files made with new versions of pg_dump.**

That was six months before PostgreSQL 11 was released, so an installation that supports PostgreSQL 11 is not supposed to use an older pg_restore. I'm not sure what exactly is "Azure Data Studio" in terms of the software stack it provides, but it looks like it has an outdated version of pg_restore that is not suitable for your needs.

Comment: The problem went away when i used an older version of psql to do the restore. So i did the restore from OTHER than azure data studio

Comment: And this didn't work for PSQL 11. So it seems to me that the new client isn't backwards compatible. Which is a little silly i think... but good to know that postgres database backups will eventually be stale and unusable over time

Comment: @ZachSmith: can you add the output of `pg_restore --version` for the one that didn't work?

Comment: output is added

Comment: @ZachSmith: thanks. I can't understand how it does not work for you though because this exact version of pg_restore 11.4 has no problem for me with archives version 1.13, as expected.

Comment: The archive was actually created by PostgreSQL V9.4

Comment: @ZachSmith: I think pg_restore 11.4 should restore that, and if it doesn't, it could be a bug. You may [submit it](https://www.postgresql.org/account/submitbug/), especially if it's reproducible with specific minor versions that are up-to-date in their major branch (11.4 is up-to-date, with 9.4.x it depends on `x`)

Comment: Thanks - My work around was to install an old version of postgres via docker, restore there. It will take some time to figure out how to reproduce it, if i get a chance I will do so